# How to mask input value based on length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are try to mask the input field as (999) 999-9999 x9999 but I need to show x symbol if user enters 14 characters I need to make visible the x symbol.We got output as expected.

But problem is I cant delete the characters once the character length reach 9 .

Is there any problem in this script or any better way to do this ?

**JS:**

```
$(document).delegate('#BPhone', 'keyup', function(e) {
    var Textlength = $(this).val();
    console.log(Textlength.length);

    if (Textlength.length >= 14)
        $("#BPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999 x9999");
    else
        $("#BPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="BPhone"  class="" type="tel"  value="" maxlength="20"  placeholder="">
```

Comment: Sorry man! not getting your problem...wat do you mean by "i cant delete the characters if character length reach 9" ??

Comment: due to else condition in the code, you will not be able to delete character beyond 9 as it is getting masked